# How to add query parameter to routes in Lumen?

Tags: lumen

I am trying to know how to add query parameters to routes in Lumen

this is an example of a route I created

```
$app->get('/product/{apikey}','ProductController@getProduct');
```

This works when I use

> http://api.lumenbased.com/product/10920918

but I would like to use it like this

> http://api.lumenbased.com/product/?apikey=10920918

I tried this

```
$app->get('/product/?apikey={apikey}','ProductController@getProduct');
```

But this gives me MethodNotAllowedHttpException

I would like to know how to write routes with query parameters in Lumen ?

Comment: It will be very nice if the downvoter also adds a reason for the downvote

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do:

```
$app->get('/product','ProductController@getProduct');
```

and use:

```
$request->get('apikey')
```

in the `ProductController@getProduct` function.

<sup>(That said, validating an API key is better done via middleware...)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the recommendation I implemented a middleware using jwt
$app->get('/product',['middleware' => 'jwt.auth','uses' => 'ProductController@getProduct']);